# Examples where Rolle's Theorem fails for following

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> **Rolle's Theorem**: Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and is differentiable on $(a,b)$. If $f(a) = f(b)$, then there is a number $c \in (a,b)$ for which $f'(c) = 0.$

Give an example where Rolle's Theorem fails if the following hypothesis is omitted:

(a) $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(a) = f(b)$ but $f$ not differentiable on $(a,b)$.

Example: $f(x) = |x|$

(b) f is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f(a) = f(b)$, but $f$ not continuous on $[a,b]$

Example: differentiability implies contininous not sure.

(c)$f$ is continouous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ but $f(a) \neq f(b)$

Example: $f(x) = \sin{(x)}$

Comment: Okay, and what's your question?

Comment: (b) for instance $f(x)=x$ for $x\in (0,1)$ and $f(0)=f(1)=-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $a<b$. For part (a) one example is $f(x)=|x-(a+b)/2|.$ For (b) note that if $f$  is differentiable on $(a,b)$ then it is continuous on $(a,b)$ but not necessarily at $a$ or at $b.$ For example $f(x)=x$ for $x\in (a.b),$ and $ f(a)=f(b).$ Regardless of the value of $f(a),$ this function $f$ can't be continuous at both $a$ and $b.$ For (c) one example is $f(x)=x$ .

Answer (score 1):

For (b), differentiability implies continuity only at points where the function is differentiable. In this case we are given $f$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$,  so it can still be discontinuous at $a$  or $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $f$ is not continuous at $a$ or $b$, then it is possible that $f(a)$ or $f(b)$ is undefined. Then Rolles Theorem cannot be used.

Comment: It is given that $f(a) = f(b)$, so $f$ *has* to be defined at both $a$ and $b$.